Why does my UV sphere render have this weird black circle shaped artifacts on it?

I'm pretty new to Blender so this might have an easy solution, but why is there weird circle shaped artifacts on my UV sphere? FYI I'm using three lights for this infinity background, two in the sides and one in the front. The texture applied to the UV sphere has also displacement, normal and roughness mapping, and i have already tried playing around with their values to see if they were to do anything.

Hello and welcome. It is hard to guess without more info about your textures. It could the displacement or something else.

Thanks dude, the problem seemed to be the amount of scale I applied to the displacement of the material, it was too high (like 0.5) when in fact i just needed like 0.1-0.2. The fact is, when there is no displacement the artifacts don't appear, but as soon as there is some scaling to the displacement being made, they start showing up. The more I apply scaling to the displacement, the more noticeable the weird visual bug is. Thats why I'm using a pretty low number for it now.

Do NOT edit your answer into the question. Post it as an answer instead.

As @TheLabCat already mentions in the other answer, the precision is a crucial point. Since gradients in pixel-based textures naturally have to change values in steps from one pixel to another, sooner or later this will result in visible stepping artifacts.
On the left is a low-res texture with a low displacement scale of 0.5, on the right the same texture with a high displacement scale of 4. Of course, the higher the scale, the more extreme the height step from one pixel to the next, so the more extreme the shadows and therefore the visible stepping in the displacement:

Usually it is better for displacement to have height maps with higher resolutions and maybe even a higher bit depth to get smoother transitions. For example, here on the left is again the texture from before, it is an 8-bit PNG with a resolution of only 160 × 90 pixels. On the right the texture has basically the same image, but it is a 16-bit PNG with a resolution of 1920 × 1080 pixels:

What sometimes can work in your favour is having a lower mesh resolution to even out the ugly steps in low resolution gradients. If you just imagine the stepping as a kind of "high detail" in the texture, then obviously reducing the mesh resolution loses some of these details and can help smoothening the surface. On the left the already known low-res texture, the plane has a Subdivision Surface modifier set to a Levels Viewport value of 6. On the right it is the same low-res texture, but the modifier now only has a Levels  Viewport value of 1:

But while it helps in this case, it might be a problem in other cases. For such a smooth gradient this might work quite often, but if for example you have some mountain height map with high detail, the result with a low level subdivision is of course not so great as with a higher resolution. Although with highly detailed maps, there is in general less visible stepping because the detail can conceal it better. Below an example for a high-res map on the plane with subdivision level 1 on the left and level 6 on the right:

To sum it all up, without knowing your mesh and texture, in general you can say there are three components which work together to create issues of this kind, the texture quality, the mesh resolution and the displacement strength. To which extent each of these components contributes to a problem depends on the specific case. A main factor is surely the texture quality, a bad texture can always only be compensated to a certain amount.

The problem here is either low precision in the displacement texture, or decent precision being spread too far (more likely the case). Images on computers have discrete steps in brightness, and if you spread those steps across too much displacement height, you start noticing the jumps between them. As you discovered, you can turn down the scale of the displacement to make the stepping not so noticeable (essentially making the same steps spam a shorter “height”, giving the desired illusion of a gradual ramp).
